# Matlab: Help in running toolbox for Kalman filter

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I have AR(1) model with data samples $N=500$ that is driven by a random input sequence x. THe observation y is corrupted with measurement noise $v$ of zero mean. The model is

`y(t) = 0.195y(t-1) + x(t) + v(t)` where x(t) is  generated as randn(). I am unsure how to represent this as a state space model and how to estimate the parameters $a$ and the states. I tried the state space representation would be

```
d(t) = \mathbf{a^T} d(t) + x(t)

y(t) = \mathbf{h^T}d(t) + sigma*v(t)
```

sigma =2. 
I cannot understand how to perform parameter and state estimation. Using the toolbox mentioned below, I checked the Equations of KF to be matching with those in textbooks. However, the approach for parameter estimation is different. I will appreciate a recommendation for the implementation procedure.

Implementation 1:
I am following the implementation here : [Learning Kalman Filter](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38302-kalman-filter-package). This implementation does not use Expectation Maximization to estimate the parameters of AR model and it finds out the Covariance of the process noise. In my case, I don't have a process noise, but an input $x$.

Implementation 2: [Kalman Filter by Kevin Murphy](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/Kalman/kalman_download.html) is another toolbox which uses EM for parameter estimation of AR model. Now, it is confusing since both the implementations uses different approach for parameter estimation.
I am having a tough time figuring out the correct approach, the state space model representation and the code. Shall appreciate recommendations on how to proceed.

I ran the first implementation for the KalmanARSquareRoot technique and the result is completely different. There is Exponential Moving Average Smoothing being performed and a MA filer of length 30 being used. The toolbox runs fine if I run the Demo examples. But on changing the model, the result is extremely poor. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Do I need to change the equations of KF for my time series?

In the second implementation, I cannot figure out what and where to change the Equations.

In general, if I have to use these tools, then do I need to change the KF equations for every time series model? How do I write the Equations myself if these toolboxes are inappropriate for all the time series model - AR, MA, ARMA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have a bit of experience with Kalman Filters, so take this with a grain of salt.

It seems you shouldn't need to change the equations at all. Working with the second package (learn_kalman), you can create an A0 matrix of size [length(d(t)) length(d(t))]. C0 is the same, and in your case the initial state probably makes sense to be the Identity matrix (unlike your A0. All you need to do is choose a good initial condition.

However, I took a look at your system (plotted an example) and it seems noise dominates your system. KF is an optimal estimator but I have not known it to reject that much noise. It only guarantees a reduced covariance...which means that if your system is mostly dominated by noise, you will calculate a bad model that estimates your system given the noise!

Try plotting [d f] where d is the initial data and f is calculated using the regressive formula <strike>f(t) = C * A * f(t-1)</strike> :

> f(t) = A * f(t-1)
>   ; y(t) = C * f(t)

That is, pretend as if there is no noise but using the estimated AR model. You will see that it rejects all the noise and 'technically' models the system well (since the only unique behaviour is at the very beginning).

For example, if you have a system with A = 0.195, Q=R=0.l then you will converge to an A = 0.2207 but it still isn't good enough. Here the problem is that your initial state is so low, that within a few steps of data and you are essentially at 0 accounting for noise. Naturally KF can converge to a LOT of model solutions that are similar. Any noise will throw off even the best initial condition.

If you increase the resolution of your data in some way (e.g. larger initial condition, more refined timesteps) you will see a good fit. Ex, changing your initial condition to 110 and you'll find the two curves similar, though the model is still fairly different.

I am not aware of any approach to model your data well. If the noise variance is in fact 1 and your system converges to 0 that quickly, it seems doomed to not be effectively modelled since you just don't capture any unique behaviour in the dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time to go through the problem. I have 2 Questions could you please share your insights? (1) if the model is driven by noise x(t) is there any range for the noise variance? (2) if x(t) is a pseudo random sequence that is generated after quantizing the output time series of a deterministic nonlinear system, then what would the representation of the state space  model be?

Comment: @SKM , If x(t) is normally distributed noise (white noise) then it should be filtered out by KF. I do not know of any formula that bounds the noise variance, however your model behaviour should probably exceed the bounds of the 1st standard deviation, i.e. your standard deviation is 1 then model behaviour shouldn't be bounded by a constant C +/- 1. As for (2), that depends on the distribution of x(t); it isn't normal so it may not filtered effectively. What is your goal with this? Are you trying to model the system as a function of x(t) as well?

Comment: For (2) When an IIR (AR) model is considered then x(t), the PRBS is the excitation signal. In another case, for FIR (MA) model, the x(t) is the input and well as the excitation signal that drives the model. I do not know the distribution of x(t) whether it is normal or not. Read in many papers that a sequence of 0/1 is modeled as Bernoulli-Gaussian or even as a mixture of Gaussians.

Comment: Okay so you are filtering out x(t) then. Since it isn't purely a gaussian, I don't think its proven to be completely filtered out - however it will work. This shouldn't change your model. Kalman Filters work on the basis that the model you create IS Autoregressive (linear models). Extended Kalman Filters (EKF) are do work with non-linear models. There is work on dual extended kalman filters. You should read up on EKF.

Comment: The KF equations will not change, true but if I want to estimate the parameters of AR model, then I need to use Expectation Maximization and Smoothing. For this I am following http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/course04/tr-96-2.pdf .I know I am asking a lot more from you, but it will be a relief if you can say what I have to change. Kevin Murphy also follows the same instructions but notations are different.